# HTTP Sony's Audio Control API

Tags: postman, sony-audio-control-api

I have some problem with the Audio control API by Sony using postman. Why post request from the screen didn't work?

[image]

Why is it working when I call getPowerStatus?

[image]

Comment: Check what parameters you can pass and what are the authorized values.

Comment: I check on : https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/hardware-overview/api-references/svs/setpowerstatus . And it's say that I can pass standby as argument...

Comment: What kind of API is that? And what is the exact problem?

Comment: Audio control API by sony (link: https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/#overview-content ) .  As it is at attached screen, I can't control my device, because when i try set power status, device return Illegal argument.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided what SONY device you trying to send the command to so I can't say for sure, but not all devices support the "standby" status.

It can be a bit confusing that you can't send "standby" and then you send "off" the status is set to "standby" this is controlled by the setting "QuickStart/Network Standby :ON" that setts that "off" is resulting in status "standby".

So try using

> "status": "off"

and the status will be "standby"